# htaccess: content doesn't seem to get cache'd

Tags: .htaccess, caching

This is my code for cacheing my website in the user's browsers:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# cache images/pdf docs for 30 days
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ttf|woff|eot|svg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public, must-revalidate"
Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

# cache html/htm/xml/txt diles for 10 days
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl|css|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

When I check my website's performance on http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ it doesn't seem like it's getting cache'd.

Is there anything wrong with the code? Or could it have something to do with a deeper server setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing mod_headers and mod_expires on the server. Quite useful if you're going to use their functions...